# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error After CIFS mount

Tags: iis

Web site had been running normally on Windows IIS 10 and .net 3.5 until the web site root directory was shared and was then mounted on Ubuntu via:
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=,password= //IP/fis /mnt/share

Error Code:  0x80070005
Config Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
\?\D:...\web.config

Comment: According to the error you provided, this seems to be a permission issue, you can also enable FRT to view the detailed error log: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 0):

After hours of googling and trying, I finally solved the problem by using workarounds.

I zipped the web directory and transfer to my Linux notebook. Unzipped it and zipped again on Ubuntu. I then transferred the new zipped file back to Windows. I unzipped it to a a folder which had not ever been mounted via SMB/CIFS. I created a new web site on the ever new folder and used a new pool. Everything was new and everything worked.

I removed all shares but the problem did get resolved until I used the above workaround. Is this a sever bug of IIS?